# nodejs - How to correctly serve vue app from express

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, child-process

I have a cli script that I'm converting to a local webapp using express to run a local server and pkg to create an executable that will include all the needed files. I'm using vue for the front-end and during the app development I didn't have any issue. I've tried to do a test build and when I try to launch the app I will get this error message in the opened browser tab `Error: cannot GET /`.

In my express routes I didn't created the default path for the root `/` so I suppose that the problem is with this aspect. I've correctly added the `express.static()` middleware but I'm not sure if I need to send the `index.html` file that run the vue app using express. How I configure correctly the root endpoint to serve the vue app?

Another small thing about the problem, how I can launch google chrome or default browser in linux using the `exec()` function of node `child_process` module?

Can anyone help me please?

```js
    async openBrowser(){
        this.app.use(express.static(this.assets));
        this.app.use(express.json());
        this.app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

        http.createServer(this.app).listen(8990, () => {
            console.log(chalk.yellowBright('Starting quizist...'));
            switch(process.platform){
                case 'darwin':
                    this.child = exec('open --new -a "Google Chrome" --args "http://localhost:8990"');
                    break;
                case 'win32':
                    this.child = exec('start chrome http://localhost:8990');
                    break;
            }
        });
    
        // I have added the root endpoint but it's not clear for me how to serve the vue app
        this.app.get('/', (req, res) => {
            
        });

        this.app.get('/init', (req, res) => {
            this.extractQuestions();
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.send(JSON.stringify(this.askQuestions));
        });

        this.app.post('/checkanswer', async (req, res) => {
            this.userAnswer = req.body;
            const data = await this.checkAnswers();
            res.setHeader('Content-Type','applications/json');
            res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        });

        this.app.get('/results', (req, res) => {
            const data = {  
                userScore: this.score,
                questionsNumber: this.askQuestions.length,
                answeredQuestions: this.answeredQuestions,
                correctAnswers: this.correctAnswers
            }
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
    }
```

Comment: `this.assets` is the name of the folder that contains all the static files? including the index.html file? maybe try access http://localhost:8990/index.html instead of 
just http://localhost:8990

Comment: yes, it's the folder that contains all the client files. I've already tried to acces it directly but the error still remain.

Comment: try `this.app.use(express.static(__dirname + this.assets));` when your `this.assets` should start with `/`

Comment: `this.assets`  is a reference to a path that is formatted using `path.format({dir: __dirname, base: 'asseys/vueapp'})`. I'm using now `res.sendFile('index.html', {root: this.assets});` inside the `app.get('/')` I think it will do the trick?

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best way to do it, but I don't know why serving the static files is not working for you

Comment: I'm new to express so I've looked at the documentations and on some examples, but there is sure a better way. I was thinking that `app.use(express.static())` was responsable to serve files on all routes but maybe in my use case it will not work after the app is packed using pkg?

Comment: maybe try using a simple string instead of `path.format({dir: __dirname, base: 'asseys/vueapp'})`? try this and see if it works `this.app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/asseys/vueapp'));`

Comment: which app is packed using pkg? the vue app?

Comment: the whole app! https://github.com/vercel/pkg

Comment: I would suggest you try starting your server without the packaging it with pkg and see if it works - that way you can isolate the problem.